# Connecting Akka HTTP directly to an Akka Stream Flow

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I've looked through the examples at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/introduction.html for Akka HTTP routing and strangely for something built on top of Akka Streams none of the examples connect to a stream.

Can somebody show a simple example of creating a Java DSL flow (not Scala please), and then connecting a Route directly to that flow?

Or am I missing the point and it's not possible but requires some CompletionStage code within the Route to wait for a result of glue code that calls a Flow?

Edit: to clarify the flow can do something like append a string to a posted request body.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you want that stream to be doing? The http entity is a stream of bytes, your response can be a stream. And there’s various other ways to connect depending on your use case - are you streaming data in, out, or through? From where etc. Some examples are here https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit: to clarify the flow can do something like append a string to a posted request body.

Michał's answer contains good links, so please give them a read. Akka HTTP is by default and always streaming with its data -- e.g. the entities. So for example to do a streaming "echo" which at the same time adds a suffix, you could do something like this:

```
path("test", () ->
  // extract the request entity, it contains the streamed entity as `getDataBytes`
  extractRequestEntity(requestEntity -> {

  // prepare what to add as suffix to the incoming entity stream:
  Source<ByteString, NotUsed> suffixSource = 
    Source.single(ByteString.fromString("\n\nADDS THIS AFTER INCOMING ENTITY"))

  // concat the suffix stream to the incoming entity stream
  Source<ByteString, Object> replySource = requestEntity.getDataBytes()
    .concat(suffixSource);

    // prepare and return the entity:
    HttpEntity.Chunked replyEntity = HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.TEXT_PLAIN_UTF8, replySource);
    return complete(StatusCodes.OK, replyEntity);
  })
);
```

Having that said, there is numerous ways to make use of the streaming capabilities, including framed [JSON Streaming](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/source-streaming-support.html) and more. You should also give the [docs page about implications of streaming](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html) a read.

Comment: Would this code exert backpressure on HTTP requests? If not, is there a way of changing it so that a slow implementation of suffixSource exerts backpressure?

Comment: Anything that is an akka stream would and will Back-Pressure when needed

Comment: To clarify, is this all the same stream, or are there two streams where the back-pressure of the second stream does not effect the other? (Or two streams where the second does cause back-pressure on the other?).

Comment: What two streams? The entity is one stream, and you connected to it, it is the same stream. For more of a discussion rather than a QA you may want to check out the discuss forums or akka?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking to clarify; I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using akka streams to complete a route is definitely possible. It involves either:

- a web socket route, see [examples](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html) in the docs, or
- a chunked http response (since you typically do not know the size of the response if it's fed from a stream). You can [create a Chunked Entity](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka-http/current/akka/http/javadsl/model/HttpEntities.html#createChunked-akka.http.javadsl.model.ContentType-akka.stream.javadsl.Source-) from an akka stream Source of ByteStrings
- you can also use other response types if the response size is known in advance, see docs for [HttpEntity](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#httpentity) about their specifics